# How can I achieve a similar menu view? [iOS]

Tags: ios, menu

Is there a way to achieve this menu easily with the sdk or do I have to make it manually (combining an overlay view and other view with the buttons)?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's UIActionSheet class from standard UIKit framework

Answer (score 0):

Easy example from [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIActionSheet.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIActionSheet) of `UIActionSheet` extended a bit by me to fire call action.

[image]
Delcare in the global scope of the ViewController:
 `UIActionSheet * actionSheet;` and `UIView * yourView;`

Int the viewDidLoad:

```
actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                             delegate:self
                             cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                             destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete Note"
                             otherButtonTitles:@"Call",@"Add a Contact",nil];

[yourView = self.view]
```

To fire the menu by some declared button with IBAction you will need:

```
-(IBAction)viewMapButton:(id) sender
{
    [actionSheet showInView:yourView];

}
```

To take appropriate action depending on user choice declare following method and check what `[actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex]` was equal to:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet
        clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
        {
        NSString * what_action = [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
        NSLog(@"The %@ button was tapped.", what_action);
             if ([what_action isEqualToString:@"Call"])
                 {
                 NSString *phoneNumber = [[NSString alloc] 
                        initWithString:@"telprompt:1234567890"];
                 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
                        openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
                 }
}
```

[NOTE: Firing of call does not work on iOS Simulator]